# How to combine same color with different sizes in one row using sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm currenly working on combining color with different sizes and align it in one row because i'm going to display it in a table

Here's my SQL Query

```
SELECT 
    a.materialnumber, a.color, SUM(a.qty) as qty, c.CurrentSRP , a.size
FROM 
    table1 a, table2 c, table3 d
WHERE 
    a.stoID = 11 
    AND a.stoprocessID = 69  
    AND a.plantcode = 'PB001'
    AND a.materialnumber = c.StockCode 
    AND a.size = c.Size 
    AND a.color = c.Color 
    AND a.stoprocessID = d.stoprocessID
    AND a.plantcode = d.plantcode 
    AND a.materialnumber = '123456' 
    AND a.color = 'BLACK'
GROUP BY  
    a.materialnumber, a.color, a.qty, a.size, c.CurrentSRP
```

The result is

```
  STOCKNUM    COLOR    QTY    PRICE   SIZE
  -----------------------------------------
  123456      BLACK     2      800      32
  123456      BLACK     1      800      36
```

Under the Stocknum 123456 there's 1 color on it with 2 different size i want to display in it only one row

And I will align it on the table like this

```
  STOCK NUM      COLOR     24   25   26   27   28   29   30    32   34   36

   123456        BLACK     0    0    0    0    0    0    0     2    0     1
```

That should be the output in my html

But i ended up with this output

```
  **STOCK NUM      COLOR     24   25   26   27   28   29   30    32   34   36**
   123456          BLACK     0    0    0    0    0    0    0     2    0     0
   123456          BLACK     0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0    0     1
```

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Google "MySQL pivot query"

Comment: Show the code that created the output you ended up with.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: If you are not going to use QTY and PRICE then don't group by them as well, and as @TimBiegeleisen pointed out you need to Pivot the results.

Comment: Can you add the screenshot of your sample data.